# Using member functions to deal with objects in the heap (c++)

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm a beginner with C++, and this is a pretty basic syntax question, but i can't seem to find an answer elsewhere. Any input would be welcome. Here is a simplified version of the problem.

Say I have a class 'pair'

```
class pair
   {
   int a;
   int b;
   public:
   pair(int x,int y)
     {
     a=x;
     b=y;
     }
   int lookup()
      {
      return this->a+b;
      }
    };
```

Then i instanciate and copy that instance to a spot on the heap.

```
int func()
{
...
pair test(1,2);
pair *ptr=new pair;
*ptr=test;
}
```

Now here is the key.  I don't destroy this memory allocation after the function ends.  I want to use it later in this other function.  The problem is, i would prefer to keep it in the heap and NOT have to copy it over to the stack(in the actual program it is very large). I would therefore like to do something like this:

```
int otherfunc()
{
...
int sum=*ptr.lookup;
}
```

but I get a compiler error.  I end up having to do something like:

```
int otherfunc()
{
...
point temp=*ptr;
int sum=temp.lookup;
}
```

While this works, it is redundant, and when dealing with really large things it can even potentially cause an overflow.  Anyone know the syntax for calling the method using the pointer while keeping it on the heap?  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you could just write `pair* ptr = new pair(1, 2);`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
int sum = ptr->lookup();
```

And as an aside, this:

```
return this->a+b;
```

Would probably be better as just this:

```
return a+b;
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `*ptr.lookup` will be interpreted as `*(ptr.lookup)`, which is why you get the syntax error because `ptr.lookup` does not make sense. You'll need to tell the compiler  dereference `ptr` first by using the parenthesis: `(*ptr).lookup`.

Because pointers are common in C (and C++), the `(*a).b` can be written in a simpler form: `a->b`.

Also, `lookup` is a function even if it does not take any parameters. You need to call it with `()`:

```
int sum=ptr->lookup();
```